# JS Framework for server-heavy and/or client-light pages

Tags: web-development, javascript, frameworks

I've been reading articles [such as this one that indicates web development has evolved to use JS frameworks](http://ruoyusun.com/2013/04/06/journey-from-dhtml-to-ember-js-angular-js.html).  Where I work, we have a massive website with many existing web applications that are already established and are server side heavy.

One article I read said that the DOM manipulation/jQuery method leads to unmaintanable spaghetti code, and that you should strive to use a JS MV* framework.  However, sometimes I just have a fairly simple list of items generated from the server; something like:

```
<div class=shower data-id=1>show</div>
<ul><li class=hider data-id=1>one</li></ul>
//js
$(".shower").on("click", function () {
    $(".hider[data-id=" + $(this).data("id") + "]").show();
});
```

...and that would pretty much be the extend of the JS on that page.  According to the MV* framework disciples, the need to reference specific classes or attributes in the JS is a problem and models should be used instead.  However, it seems like overkill to include a massive library for creating rich applications to handle some fairly trivial DOM manipulation and animations.

Is there a JS framework in existence that bridges the gap between complete front-end stack frameworks and tightly coupled HTML/JS?  If not, how could I write such code to avoid this coupling?

Additionally is there any reason to push strongly for making the switch to such a framework for established server-heavy applications (especially in cases where we have to support JavaScript being turned off)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author of the article you linked seems to have forgotten about server-side HTML generation completely.  You don't need all that JS ceremony to create a data-driven web page; the JS is there to augment the page, not generate it.

That said, none of these JS frameworks is all that large.  "Massive library" is a mischaracterization.  I suspect that if you make the attempt to write such code to avoid tight coupling, you'll be reinventing Backbone/Ember/Angular anyway.

If you're genuinely worried about the library size, use [Resig's Micro-Templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/), which weighs in at about thirty lines of javascript.  Alternatively, you can get a custom-tailored recommendation for a JS framework at one of the links below.

**See Also**
http://microjs.com/#
http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/

Comment: So you think it would be worth investing in choosing and using a particular framework consistently even in trivial cases above?  I have read tutorials who assert that such would be overkill for an application that's already server-heavy.

Comment: I essentially made the same assertion in the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: So when you are writing JS-augmenting code rather than actual HTML generation/data-bindings is it okay to have a coupling of DOM and JS symbols or should it still be avoided (or can it?)

Comment: That coupling is sort of the raison d'etre of Javascript, is it not?  Unless you're trying to build a generalized JS library, I wouldn't be too worried about coupling JS with the DOM.  Actually, the way you avoid tight coupling is by referring to CSS classes instead of specific DIV's.